# How to speed up the model's loading phase in tensorflow.js?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow.js

System
Browser: Edge/Chrome;
tfjs version: 2.7.0;

Description
Load a trained MobileNet V2 model with tensorflow.js in a specific page take 10+ seconds one time.
Not only for the first time, but takes the same 10+ seconds every time I open the page.
When the loading phase is completed, the prediction phase is fast.

But I want to know how to speed up the loading phase, because it appears a not very good performance like this.

The code of loading below:

```
async function loadModel(model_path) {
    model = await tf.loadLayersModel(
        model_path
    );
}
```

The model size is only 9MB.

Comment: Could you check what backend are you using with this `console.log(tf.getBackend());`?

Comment: @yudhiesh Thanks for your answer. It appears to be `webgl`.

Comment: So the `WebGL` backend is the fastest there is especially for this model but this is definitely odd as I have done the same thing previously and it was never this slow. When converting the model did you quantize it?

Comment: @yudhiesh  Do you mean quantize the training data by divide .255? I convert the `.h5` model file using `tfjs`,  a public python lib. It produces several files including  one `.json` file and three `.bin` file. Then when I try to load the model using `.json` file in javascript. It takes at least 10 seconds.

Comment: No quantization basically shrinks the model size to gain performance while a slight loss in accuracy. You can try converting the model again with quantization applied by referring to [FAQ number 4](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter#faq). Then try that model instead it will be faster.

Comment: @yudhiesh I get through the material you provide and try to quantize my file like this `--quantize_uint16`. But I don't find the loading phase become faster. My files turn to only 4MB. I now guess it may be caused by the compile of webgl?

Comment: Could you include more code about where this function is called?

Comment: @yudhiesh I once try to call the function only and directly with the html page establishes or with a button onclick. But it turn out to be the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the cdnjs tensorflow to the latest version? Check it out [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/tensorflow)

I had similar challenge and that worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add more details when you provide a "link-answer" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer